# Update python script called from other script

Tags: python, call

I have one small python script called genData that contains a function genWork that takes 5 arguments. In another script, I do

```
from genData import genWork
```

and then call the function genWork(1, 2, 3, 4, 5). That worked just fine, and the other script runs as expected.

I then edited the function genWork in the genData file and it now takes 7 arguments. I keep the same import lines in the other script, and use the function as genWork(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). I get the error:

```
TypeError: genWork() takes exactly 5 arguments (7 given)
```

So, I am guessing somehow the genData script did not actually update? I tried deleting the .pyc file that got created, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you click *save* after you edited the file?

Comment: Did you also check if there is any `sys.argv` related comparison somewhere in the file?

Comment: @Bharadwaj hmm, no 'sys.argv' stuff going on, as the second script just calls the function with arguments inside it, not taking arguments from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try removing .pyc files and running again ( assuming you saved your files). The files should have been updated automatically sometimes that doesn't work as expected.

I wanted to add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm dumb, I figured out my problem. (Answering in case others have a similar problem.)

I had an old version of genData saved in a different directory. That directory was in my path but the one I was working in was NOT in my path. So, when I imported the genWork function from genData, it was importing that old version from the other directory.